# NewsArticle: "logo.itemtype has an invalid value"

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, rdfa

I tested this RDFa on Google Structured Data Testing Tool:

```html
<main vocab="http://schema.org"> 
<article typeof="NewsArticle">
  <h2 property="headline">Wie instaliert Virtual Box in Windows 10</h2>
  <span property="name" value="Virtual Box"/>
  <span property="mainEntityOfPage" value="http://google.de"/>
  <span property="datePublished" value="2019-03-07"/>
  <span property="dateModified" value="2019-03-17"/>
  <span property="publisher" typeof="Organization">

      <span property="logo" value="https://schema.org/"></span>
      <img src="http://htmlkurss.xyz/index.php/Bilder/Virtualbox.png" alt="Logo"/>

  </span>

  <p property="text">Virtual Box ist eine Virtualisierungssoftware, die viele Betriebessysteme ,... 
  </p>
  <p property="author" typeof="Person">Autor: <span property="name">ich</span></p>

  <p>Korrekturen: <span property="editor">me</span></p>
</article>
```

and the SDTT tells me that

> `logo.itemtype` has an invalid value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```html
> <span property="logo" value="https://schema.org/"></span>
> ```

This is invalid HTML, the `span` element can’t have a `value` attribute. And if it could have one, the `logo` property value would be `https://schema.org/`, but that’s of course not the logo. You probably meant this:

```html
<link property="logo" href="/index.php/Bilder/Virtualbox.png" />
```

While this is valid Schema.org, Google expects an `ImageObject` value for the `logo` property, so you could use this:

```html
<span property="logo" typeof="ImageObject">
  <img property="contentUrl url" src="/index.php/Bilder/Virtualbox.png" alt="VirtualBox"/>
</span>
```

(Note that "Logo" [is not](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86758/17633) a suitable `alt` value in this context.)

Comment: Very Thanks ! , Mila ezker! auf meine Sprache

Comment: With , property="contentUrl url" , google warnin me ,(Die Eigenschaft contentUrl wird von Google nicht als Objekt des Typs Organization erkannt.)

Comment: @biotza: It seems that you added it at the wrong place then. You have to add the `logo` with `typeof="ImageObject"` (!) inside of `Organization`.